# How to use AntiXss if the JSON string has unclosed html tags

Tags: c#, xss

Our application allows a user to copy text from any source and input it into a text field. A sample of this text might look like this (note the unclosed `<` tag):

```
From Sender 
Sent Monday, March 6, 2017 1132 AM
To Receiver <receiver@domain.co.za

Some email text go go here.....
```

The user might also want to insert malicious script tags, since it is a free text field, so the text might end up like this:

```
From Sender 
Sent Monday, March 6, 2017 1132 AM
To Receiver <receiver@domain.co.za

Some email text go go here <script>alert("0");</script>.....
```

We are using Microsoft's AntiXssLibrary V4.3 to sanitize the request (using `GetSafeHtmlFragment()`), however, the sanitized output strips out everything from the first unclosed `<`, thus rendering the request as:

```
From Sender 
Sent Monday, March 6, 2017 1132 AM
To Receiver
```

I am now attempting to iterate through the initial raw request, and remove any unclosed tags, leaving the correctly closed tags to be handled by the library.
The issue I am having is to figure out how to move to the next unclosed tag, after removing the first index of the tag.

Below is a sample of my attempt:

```
private string SanitizeInputStream(string inputStream)
        {
            var firstStartBracketPosition = inputStream.IndexOf("<");

            while(firstStartBracketPosition >= 0)
            {
                var firstEndBracketPosition = inputStream.IndexOf(">");

                if (firstEndBracketPosition < 0)
                    inputStream = inputStream.Remove(firstStartBracketPosition, 1);

                firstStartBracketPosition = inputStream.IndexOf("<");
            }

            return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Microsoft.Security.Application.Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(inputStream));
        }
```

So the idea was to loop through the incoming request, find the first index of an open tag, as well as the first index of a closed tag. If the closed tag was not found, the first index of the open tag is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should Do the job

```
 private string SanitizeInputStream(string inputStream)
    {
        var firstStartBracketPosition = inputStream.IndexOf("<");

        while (firstStartBracketPosition >= 0)
        {
            var secondOpenBracketPosition = inputStream.IndexOf("<", firstStartBracketPosition + 1);
            var firstEndBracketPosition = inputStream.IndexOf(">", firstStartBracketPosition + 1);
            if (firstEndBracketPosition < secondOpenBracketPosition)
            {
                if (firstEndBracketPosition < 0)
                    inputStream = inputStream.Remove(firstStartBracketPosition, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                inputStream = inputStream.Remove(firstStartBracketPosition, 1);
            }
            if (inputStream.Length < firstEndBracketPosition + 1)
            {
                firstStartBracketPosition = inputStream.IndexOf("<", firstEndBracketPosition + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                firstStartBracketPosition = -1;
            }
        }

        return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Microsoft.Security.Application.Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(inputStream));
    }
```